# ReactNativeFCM Notifications

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a notification with both notification and data payloads from a server to an Android app. When the application is in background and notification arrives, when I tap and open it, the data (which is an image URL) is shown to the client. So far so good. My problem is the following: After I reload javascript, FCM.getInitialNotification() is called and notification is shown to client again. I need to show it just once. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since no one knows the solution to my question and the time is running out, I have done some kind of workaround.
I stored the timestamp of the notification that is opened when getInitialNotification() is fired, so the next time application (javascript) loads, it compares the notification timestamp with the stored timestamp. Since no two same timestamps are possible, if they differ then notification data (the image) is shown to the client. In the other case, it is not shown. Done :)